# Debugging web application from Visual Studio using a specific screen resolution

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging

I would like to know if there is the possibility to set screen resolution when debugging web application.
For instance, I usually work with a 1600x900 screen size, but the customer requirement is fixed on 1024x768 resolution.
My desire is to start debugging in the browser setted to this resoluton, for the time of the debug.
Is it possibile ? Or there is some tool that allow this kind of behaviour ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can try a browser plugin like https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/ that will allow you to quickly change the resolution of the the browser your are debugging in. There's one for Chrome too (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/idhfcdbheobinplaamokffboaccidbal) and I'm sure other browsers allow you to do this too.

This may not work automatically, but you can quickly switch back an forth between resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the Windows API to try to set screen resolution from your program, if the DEBUG constant has been defined: http://dotnet.mvps.org/dotnet/faqs/?id=setscreenresolution&lang=en. However, if you have to terminate the debugger, your screen will remain set to the debug resolution. You also shouldn't release the "debug" configuration of your app without first commenting out the resolution change.

Usually, changing the screen res is something a desktop app should never do. However, it makes a certain amount of sense here, so just make sure the released builds don't do this.

Comment: his question was for a web application.

Comment: Then he can set up the API calls in a small console app and run it as a post-build action. Or, since it's a web app, he could also again use the Win API to set the window size of his browser to 1024x768. the browser doesn't HAVE to be maximized to show you what you'd see on a screen that size.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox offers a plug-in to test a website in different resolutions, but this is just testing it with one particular browser. http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/3-firefox-plugins-test-website-resolutions/